# How to remove an element from a table that is the result of the intersection of two other tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, winforms

Good day! I`m doing a small WPF program using SQL. I have a table Zoo, table Animal and ZooAnimal that is a combination of 2 other tables. So the idea is that by ckicking on Zoo should be information about animals situated in particular Zoo + some other functionalities.

I ran into a problem with implementing "Remove Animal" button. It should remove a selected animal from the ZooAnimal table but I don`t know what SQL code must be used to do this.

I tried like this:

```
private void removeAnimal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            string query = "delete AnimalZoo Set ZooId = @ZooId where AnimalId = @AnimalId";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZooId", listZoos.SelectedValue);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AnimalId", listAssociatedAnimals.SelectedValue);
            command.ExecuteScalar();

            connection.Close();
            showAssociatedAnimals();
    }
```

I will be very happy to receive any help on this.

Here is how WPF UI looks like:

[image: WPF UI Main Window]

Database is as follows:

[image: SQL Database]

ZooAnimal Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ZooAnimal] (
[Id]       INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[ZooId]    INT NOT NULL,
[AnimalId] INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [AnimalFK] FOREIGN KEY ([AnimalId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Animal] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [ZooFK] FOREIGN KEY ([ZooId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Zoo] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

);

Answer (score 0):

```sql
delete AnimalZoo where AnimalId = @AnimalId and ZooId = @ZooId
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, in your c# code you call ExecuteScalar to execute the Delete statement.
This SQL used provides no fields to be returned (it is not a query), so you should better use ExecuteNonQuery instead.

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = "delete from ZooAnimal where AnimalId = @AnimalId and ZooId = @ZooId";
```